# How to construct a Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo object from C++

Tags: c++, v8

I've been asked to test a library that uses v8 written in C++. Instead of testing it from nodejs, I've been asked to test it from C++.

To get an instance of the object I must pass an object of type v8::FunctionCallbackInfo, but have not been able to understand how to construct it.

Specifically, the initialize method is of the form

```
CAddon::Initialize(const  Nan::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args)
```

I've taken a look at the [documentation](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-4.8/dd/d0d/classv8_1_1_function_callback_info.html). I know that the constructor is of the form

```
FunctionCallbackIn(internal::Object **  implicit_args,
                            internal::Object **     values,
                            int     length,
                            bool    is_construct_call )
```

I know that the two implicit args are two string, know their values. But I don't understand how to construct the object. I don't understand how to use the template. The following of course does not work:

```
v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<std::string> *callback = new v8::FunctionCallback<std::string>({ "strProcessName" , "strProjectId" }, { "test","1234556" }, 2, true);
```

How can I construct an object of type FunctionCallbackInfo ?